# Why do I get "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping" error in automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper-5

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;

namespace TestAutomapper
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<MyClassSource, MyClassDestination>());


      var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

      var source = new MyClassSource { DateTimeValue = null };

      var mapped = mapper.Map<MyClassSource, MyClassDestination>(source);
    }

  }

  public class MyClassSource
  {
    public object DateTimeValue { get; set; }
  }

  public class MyClassDestination
  {
    public DateTime? DateTimeValue { get; set; }
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
    AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException was unhandled
      HResult=-2146233088
      Message=Error mapping types.

    Mapping types:
    MyClassSource -> MyClassDestination
    TestAutomapper.MyClassSource -> TestAutomapper.MyClassDestination

    Type Map configuration:
    MyClassSource -> MyClassDestination
    TestAutomapper.MyClassSource -> TestAutomapper.MyClassDestination

    Property:
    DateTimeValue
      Source=Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
      StackTrace:
           at lambda_method(Closure , MyClassSource , MyClassDestination , ResolutionContext )
           at TestAutomapper.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\costa\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestAutomapper\TestAutomapper\Program.cs:line 22
           at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
           at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
           at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
           at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
           at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
           at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
           at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
           at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
      InnerException: 
           HResult=-2146233088
           Message=Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

    Mapping types:
    Object -> Nullable`1
    System.Object -> System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
           Source=Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
           StackTrace:
                at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Nullable`1 , ResolutionContext )
                at lambda_method(Closure , MyClassSource , MyClassDestination , ResolutionContext )
           InnerException:
```

I thought this error was solved (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1095). I am using Automapper 5.1.1.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Edit: Just to clarify, I am concerned with the handling of the null value. I understand that converting from a non-null object value to DateTime is complicated. In the real code, the actual value in the source object is null or DateTime. I thought the null is handled without errors.

Edit:

I created an extension method ToDate to convert an object to a date and I added this mapping to handle conversions from object to DateTime?:

```
cfg.CreateMap<object, DateTime?>().ConstructUsing(src => src.ToDate());
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've used AutoMapper, but I believe a map between the two types (e.g. `object` and `DateTime?`) is required to automatically map the same property name with different types. So either add a mapping between `object` and `DateTime?` (which seems icky) or use custom resolution options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the properties in your source and destination types have the same name, **AutoMapper** will try to convert from object to DateTime? which is not possible, and that's why you're getting the error you mentioned.

You need to define how you want to resolve the DateTime? property. This will work:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(
    cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<MyClassSource, MyClassDestination>()
            .ForMember(
                destination => destination.DateTimeValue,
                memberOptions => memberOptions.ResolveUsing(sourceMember =>
                {
                    DateTime dateTime;
                    return !DateTime.TryParse(sourceMember.DateTimeValue.ToString(), out dateTime) ? (DateTime?) null : dateTime;
                }));
    }
);
```

If your source member is a valid date time object, it'll be converted to date time, otherwise the destination property will get a null value.

Comment: It's surprising though because null is a valid value for a DateTime? variable. The following code: `PropertyInfo pi = typeof(MyClassDestination).GetProperty("DateTimeValue");
 MyClassDestination dst = new MyClassDestination();
 pi.SetValue(dst, null);` works just fine.

Comment: Indeed. But I think the key is that although null is a valid value for a DateTime? property, you can not guarantee it'll be always null, because the source property is an object. So, it could have any other invalid value as well, hence the error. What if the value of source property is "Foo" (a string)?

Comment: I agree with you. However, I thought that automapper provides some default conversion routines that at least handle null values (as long as the  destination is nullable) or values of types that are compatible.

Comment: @costa You're confusing the _value_ of the source with the _type_ of the source.  While Automapper may indeed map a `null` value properly, it cannot _generically_ map any object to a `DateTime?`, so it fails because there is no map defined between those two types.  The issue you link to fails when mapping between two properties of the same nullable type, which is different.

Comment: @DStanley: I don't think I confuse them. I had the expectation that, at runtime, automapper provides some kind of default conversion. In this particular case the destination property is DateTime? and the source property is object. I expected that automapper would execute at least the following code (roughly - in pseudocode): `if (source value is null and destination property type is nullable) then return null; if (source value type is the same as the destination property type) then return original value;` etc...

Comment: @costa No such "default" mapping exists.  The maps are static and are not dependent on run-time values.  Nor should they, in my opinion, because it could hide invalid maps just because some run-time values could be converted.

Comment: @DStanley: Default mappings exist otherwise automapper wouldn't work out-of-the-box. I think you mean default mappings between seemingly incompatible types, such as object -> DateTime?. I agree with you there, more or less :-) If you assign a DateTime value (DateTime.Now) to the source DateTimeValue the mapping works. If you assign DateTime.Now.ToString() it works as well. So there is some kind of default mapping but that default mapping fails to handle nulls. That's my contention.

Comment: @costa Yes that's what I meant - default mappings between incompatible types.  I'm surprised that the mapping works if the source contains a non-null `DateTime`, though.